# Stop flicker effect on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I stop the 'flicker' effect on my menu?

When I click 'Dropdown 1' the `Test 1` & `Test 2` flicker. I believe it's because I'm forcing this using the `!important` clause.

Help?

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be forcing visibility so hard in your CSS. Something like this should do:

```
$(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
$(this).closest('li').siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4dm318nn/8)**

---

A CSS adjustment shows the sub-sub menu:

```
.primary-item > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Unforuntately only `Dropdown 2` appears : http://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/5/
I need `Test 1` & `Test 2` to appear also.

Comment: Usually that's a separate operation. I'll revise.

Comment: Thank you. `Demo` doesn't seem to want to link for me :(

Comment: Perfection. Many thanks, @isherwood. Will accept answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out the `slideUp` command stopped the stuttering. So, I figured I'd check out what the selector there was catching:

```
console.log($(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()));
```

Showed me that it was actually selecting three different elements. To make sure it only selected the right answer, you can simply add `.navtoggle +` to the `.submenu` selector:

```
$(".navtoggle + .sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

### jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){        

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function(){
          $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideDown('fast');
        });

       //Hide the other panels
       $(this).parent().siblings().find(".sub-menu").slideUp('fast');    

   });
});
```

### CSS

```
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
.sub-menu {display: none;}
```